# interface org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedBlob is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay ce 6.1.1 GA for development and when I try to use service builder to retrieve the records containing a BLOB from DB I am getting the following error. I could save the BLOB to DB successfully. I researched and found that it may be an issue of jar conflicts in similar problems with different classes, but could not find exactly what is to be done or what is conflicting. Given below the stack trace.

```
09:47:04,791 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:560] Could not complete request
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.WrappedBlob is not visible from class loader
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePersistenceImpl.java:193)
    at com.speridian.portal.service.persistence.ApplicationPersistenceImpl.findByapplicantPersonId(ApplicationPersistenceImpl.java:902)
    at com.speridian.portal.service.persistence.ApplicationPersistenceImpl.findByapplicantPersonId(ApplicationPersistenceImpl.java:796)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.shard.advice.ShardPersistenceAdvice.invoke(ShardPersistenceAdvice.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy463.findByapplicantPersonId(Unknown Source)
    at com.speridian.portal.service.impl.ApplicationLocalServiceImpl.getApplicationByApplicantPersonId(ApplicationLocalServiceImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.aop.DynamicDataSourceTransactionInterceptor.invoke(DynamicDataSourceTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
```

Here is my pom.xml dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
                    <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>myPortletDependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please help!! Please ask if any more details is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to the Hibernate3.jar in my lib. Once I replaced it, everything worked well.